# Can not mount NFS from server on local network

Tags: linux, mount, connection, nfs

I set up my NFS server without doing any bigger changes in configuration files. After that I added these entries to `/etc/exports`(both paths are valid) on server(192.168.1.11):

```
/export         192.168.1.0/192.168.255.255(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
/export/users   192.168.1.0/192.168.255.255(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

Then I restarted the computer and I tried to get exports list:

```
$ showmount -e 192.168.1.11
/export        192.168.1.0/192.168.255.255
/export/users  192.168.1.0/192.168.255.255
```

According to this output there's not problem with connection. Now I want to mount `/export` to client filesystem(192.168.1.12):

```
sudo mount -t nfs4 192.168.1.11:/export /mnt
```

After typing this there's no output and I can't do anything. Another terminal line start is not being displayed. Command is stuck.

Does anybody know am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ON SERVER**

Try changing your /etc/exports to

```
/export         192.168.1.0/24(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
/export/users   192.168.1.0/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

Then run `exportfs -av`

**ON CLIENT**

`sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.1.11:/export /mnt` or `-t nfs4`

Would be nice if you could post some output from `/var/log/messages` if there's any error.

Comment: Works, thanks! Interesting is that when I connect with `-t nfs4` it throws this error: `mounting 192.168.1.11:/export failed reason given by server:No such file or directory`. It works with `-t nfs`. But: I have specified rw option, but on client I cannot write my file. Any idea?

Comment: You need to make sure both server having the same uid and guid for the files and folder. Usually distro comes with nfsnobody. `chown -R nfsnobody.nfsnobody /export`

Comment: [how-to-properly-set-permissions-for-nfs-folder-permission-denied-on-mounting-en](http://serverfault.com/questions/240897/how-to-properly-set-permissions-for-nfs-folder-permission-denied-on-mounting-en)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to mount your NFS export to the /mnt directory on your client.

You should create a mount point under /mnt, let's say /mnt/foo, and try mounting there.

Comment: still not works. I've tried /mnt/users subdirectory